# Check if type uses multiple inheritance or not

Tags: c++, templates

I have these classes:

```
class A{};
class B{};
class C : public A{};
class D : public A, public B{};
```

I want to make a template function like this:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T* arg);
```

And to make 2 specializations for it:

- one when T doesn't uses inheritance or uses single inheritance
- one when T uses multiple inheritance

Let's say `f_specialization1()` is for first case and `f_specialization2()` (I know hey must have same name, this is just a convenient convention). I want this behavior:

```
A a;
B b;
C c;
D d;

f(&a);//here f_specialization1 is called
f(&b);//here f_specialization1 is called
f(&c);//here f_specialization1 is called
f(&d);//here f_specialization2 is called
```

Is it possible to achieve this behavior?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this hacky mechanism?

Comment: The only possible use I could think of for this is if you want to do something horrible that depends on the class having a certain memory layout.

Comment: Is this function for some sort of explicit type introspection?  Otherwise, it would be unusual for a function to need a different implementation specifically for any object that happens to use multiple inheritance in its design.

Comment: as far as I know, it is not possible to do this with just c++ constructs.  however, you can build an infrastructure on top of c++ that will let you do this.  for example, create a base type Object.  have all your classes be derived from it.  track the entire inheritance hierarchy by adding code in the constructor.  otherwise, you can assume certain RTTI implementation and use that to track your inheritance hierarchy, but this isn't portable.

Comment: Not possible. What do you want to do with the value, assuming you can get it somehow?

Comment: @n.m. there is actually a (rare) use for something like this.  sometimes it is used in Java/C# via reflection where type information is better encoded than C++.  For example, A = person, B = canine, C = an adult person, D = an adult hybrid.  Someone wants to do f(o)->CanBark(); on object ptr o.  There is most likely a better design, but if you have already created the hierarchy....

Comment: @thang: huh? Please show the code.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late answer, I was on the way home:) I want to store function member pointer from my objects as raw pointers to "type"(unsafe, I know). Classes with multiple inheritance have different member function pointer representations and can't be stored in the same way as non-multiple inheritance types.

Comment: Member function pointers are not pointers, they don't have the same size as normal pointers and can't be stored together with normal pointers. Member function pointers from classes with single and multiple inheritance have the same representation.

Comment: @n.m. - the inter-operation rules in the standard in effect require that member pointers have the same representation, but Microsoft doesn't do that; they use "more efficient" representations in some situations, and the result is incompatible types.

Comment: @Felics - you're going outside the language definition, far into implementation-specific land.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I now of no such rules. Can you quote them? I wouldn't know if Microsoft did it one way or the other. I use gcc on Linux and it certainly doesn't do "that", which is probably not accidental.

Comment: There is an implicit conversion from a pointer-to-member of base into a pointer-to-member of derived, and there is an explicit conversion from a pointer-to-member of derived into a pointer-to-member of base.

Comment: @PeteBecker: oh sorry, I have misunderstood you completely, you are right.

Comment: @n.m. - I think I may have muddled things a bit when I replied to you; I was agreeing that they **should** have the same implementation, but pointing out the OP's (legitimate) compiler-specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I do not know your intent and agree that the intended behavior should be included in the question to receive better design solutions, a simple mechanism to achieve what you request is to create a blank interface that all of your multiply-inherited classes must also inherit from and to specialize for that MultipleInheritance "interface".

```
class MultipleInheritance
{
protected:
    MultipleInheritance() {}
};


class A{};
class B{};
class C : public A{};
class D : public A, public B, public MultipleInheritance {};

template<>
void f(MultipleInheritance* arg);

template<typename T>
void f(T* arg);
```

However, I personally think think this would be very much begging for a redesign at this point depending on the design constraints and it really does not allow you to do much useful since an otherwise useless type is used to select this function specialization.